# regex take string at the center

Tags: php, regex

i have this string

```
SMPN 2 Aesesa Selatan<br />SMPN 2 Aesesa Selatan<br />Desa/Kel. Lange Dhawe<br />Kec. Aesesa Selatan<br />Kab. Nagekeo<br />Nusa Tenggara Timur<br />Type : USB<br />Progress : COMPLETED
```

with regex (PHP) how do i take the second apearance of this substring "SMPN 2 Aesesa Selatan"
i tried

```
/<br\s+>(SMPN2)(.*)<\/br\s+>/
```

it takes the second starting from <br /> until the last <br /> after substring "USB"
also the first and second of "SMPN 2 Aesesa Selatan" could be different at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the negated character class in regex

```
<br \/>([^<br>]*)<br \/>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG9nD5)

Comment: anyway this [^<br>] will look for the next first occurance of <br>, am i right? new experience in regex for me..thanks a lot

Comment: @DarielPratama it is the negated character class it matches other than the <br> to match in between the <br>.yes you are correct