# Regex for finding specific strings with random center

Tags: java, regex, full-text-search

I will be reading a long String from a large number of files. I need to be able to find whether or not a specific type of pattern can be found in each String. It will have a specific string before and after some random text. Essentially; it might look like *"ABC[?????]DEF"* with the question marks being any String (most likely never longer than 50 chars, nor shorter than 15 chars).

I can't quite get this to work. I think a regex is the best way, but I don't know how to work with regexes. Anyone can help me?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: What kind of characters in the *[?????]* part? Spaces? New Lines? Only letters? You can either get what you want with `/ABC[a-e]{15,50}DEF/` (for 15 to 50 `abcde` characters) or what you don't want with something like  `/ABC[^a-e]{15,50}DEF/` which will find string UNLESS then have that number of `a-e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String pattern = "ABC.{15,50}DEF";
```

I think this could work.

I generate some random test case, you could try

```
    System.out.println("ABCes564fd5644cv81e6a7ser*oiier&%iuwdjDEF".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("ABC.{15,50.dsjfklejkfsk;dlfk;e546544}DEF".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("ABC.{15,50}*)(/;:DEF".matches(pattern)); //14 chars between
System.out.println("ABC.{15,50}*)(/;:%DEF".matches(pattern)); //15 chars between
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that java regular expressions like `ABC.{15,50}DEF` are inefficient if applied to many (!) large (!) files. Applied to `ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE...` will backtrack 35 times at every fifth position.

Efficient solutions to this problem would be:

- proximity search with search indexes (e.g. Lucene) "ABC DEF"~50
- wilcard search (mentioned in [Flexible pattern matching in strings](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=571024))
- regular expression search with non backtracking automaton ([re2j](https://github.com/google/re2j), [brics automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) or [patternsearchalgorithms](http://patternsearchalgorithms.amygdalum.net/))
- regular expression search with bitparallel automaton
- regular factor search

Unfortunately most algorithms are not available as libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

`ABC[.*]DEF`
or maybe
`ABC.*DEF`

You can be more restrictive `ABC.*{15,50}DEF`

Btw you can you this website to help yourself : https://regex101.com/

Comment: `ABC[.*]DEF` matches `ABC.DEF` or `ABC*DEF` and nothing else. `ABC.*{15,50}DEF` is invalid regex.

Answer (score 0):

I use this from ([regex take string at the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372525/regex-take-string-at-the-center)) :

```
stringPart1([^.]*)stringPart2
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bM1rD3/1/)